# Radians to Rotate Earth to Match ECI Lat/Lon with ECEF Lat/Lon

Tags: astronomy, simulations, coordinate-systems, observational-astronomy

I am attempting to model GPS Satellite positions on the globe for a set of ephemerides. I have a verified set of ECI ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial ) XYZ Coordinates and a verified set of ECEF ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF ) XYZ coordinates.

```
For example ( m ):
ECEF X 4076514.50
ECEF Y 14673598.00
ECEF Z -21793674.00

ECI X 8004604.50
ECI Y 12956032.00
ECI Z -21793674.00
```

Sometimes the signs of the ECI X and Y coordinates are opposite of the signs for the ECEF X and Y coordinates.

When I plot these locations on a globe and, obviously they do not match unless you rotate the earth by some number of radians. I can see that if you rotate the earth, the ECI coordinates follow a groundtrack that is consistent with the ECEF groundtrack, but with my current code, it is offset by different varying amounts, depending on the time of day I plot it.

Here is my code:

```
// The radians earth rotates in 1 second
double earthRotation = 0.000072921151467;

// Do something different depending on the switch position
if ( self.shouldAnimate == true ) {

    // The seconds since we started rotating
    double newRotationMultiplier = [self.eciDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.lastEciDate];

    // Seconds           // Rad/Sec        // Multiplier
    self.timeSinceOpenGlStarted = newRotationMultiplier * earthRotation;
    matrixToRotate = GLKMatrix4Rotate(matrixToRotate, self.timeSinceOpenGlStarted, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // Latch it so that when we stop rotating, it doesn't revert
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = matrixToRotate;

}
```

How do I determine the radians to rotate the earth to show an ECI positions for a time to be the same location on the rotated globe ( in terms of latitude and longitude )? That is, how do I calculate for any UTC time in a day, how much to rotate the earth about the Z ( "Up" ) axis so that the ECI coordinates agree with the ECEF coordinates and the satellites appear to be in the same position over my 3D globe?

UPDATE:

I got it to work - thanks to the answer below! Here is the code:

```
    // Get the NSDate components
    NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [currentCalendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    NSDateComponents *components = [currentCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:self.eciDate];
    [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSInteger second = [components second];

    // Get UTC in terms of decimal hours
    float utc = hour + (float)minute/60.0f + (float)second/3600.0f; // UTC is expressed in hours as a decimal number

    //NSLog(@"UTC: %f H %f M %f S %f",utc,(float)hour,(float)minute/60.0f ,(float)second/3600.0f);

    // Get the seconds since the last vernal equinox
    double secondsSinceVernalEquinox = [self.eciDate timeIntervalSinceDate:appDelegate.lastVernalEquinox];

    // Do the math
    // http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98466/radians-to-rotate-earth-to-match-eci-lat-lon-with-ecef-lat-lon
    double d = secondsSinceVernalEquinox  / ( 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0 ); // Give decimal days
    double p = 365.242187; // Length of tropical year
    double result = ( M_PI * 2 / 24 ) * ( utc - 12.0 ) + ( 2 * M_PI * d  / p );

    //NSLog(@"Radians = %f",result);

    // Seconds           // Rad/Sec        // Multiplier
    self.timeSinceOpenGlStarted = result;
    matrixToRotate = GLKMatrix4Rotate(matrixToRotate, self.timeSinceOpenGlStarted, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // Latch it so that when we stop rotating, it doesn't revert
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = matrixToRotate;
```

Comment: My first answer was not entirely accurate (I think it's about 1.8 degrees off), because $d$ should be measured from the perihelion instead of the vernal equinox, plus an extra constant. However, I found a more accurate and simpler formula; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I updated my previous answer as I found a more accurate formula.

The rotation angle $\theta$ is the angle between the vernal point and the meridian at Greenwich. This also corresponds with the [Sidereal Time at Greenwich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_time#Definition), converted to radians.

[image]

For a given UTC time and a given date, the corresponding Greenwich (Mean) Sidereal Time (in hours and decimal parts of an hour) can be calculated as
$$
\text{GMST} = 18.697\,374\,558 + 24.065\,709\,824\,419\,d,
$$
where $d$ is the interval, in UT1 days including any fraction of a day, since 2000 January 1, at 12h UT ([source: US Naval Observatory](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/GAST.php)). Of course, this 
must be reduced to the range 0h to 24h. The rotation angle is then simply
$$
\theta = \frac{2\pi}{24}\text{GMST}.
$$